# Failing to write offset data to zookeeper in kafka-storm

Tags: bigdata, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm, apache-kafka

I was setting up a storm cluster to calculate real time trending and other statistics, however I have some problems introducing the "recovery" feature into this project, by allowing the offset that was last read by the `kafka-spout` (the source code for `kafka-spout` comes from https://github.com/apache/incubator-storm/tree/master/external/storm-kafka) to be remembered. I start my `kafka-spout` in this way:

```
BrokerHosts zkHost = new ZkHosts("localhost:2181");
SpoutConfig kafkaConfig = new SpoutConfig(zkHost, "test", "", "test");
kafkaConfig.forceFromStart = false;
KafkaSpout kafkaSpout = new KafkaSpout(kafkaConfig);
TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
builder.setSpout("test" + "spout", kafkaSpout, ESConfig.spoutParallelism);
```

The default settings should be doing this, but I think it is not doing so in my case, every time I start my project, the `PartitionManager` tries to look for the file with the offsets, then nothing is found:

```
2014-06-25 11:57:08 INFO  PartitionManager:73 - Read partition information from: /storm/partition_1  --> null
2014-06-25 11:57:08 INFO  PartitionManager:86 - No partition information found, using configuration to determine offset
```

Then it starts reading from the latest possible offset. Which is okay if my project never fails, but not exactly what I wanted.

I also looked a bit more into the `PartitionManager` class which uses `Zkstate` class to write the offsets, from this code snippet:

PartitionManeger

```
public void commit() {
    long lastCompletedOffset = lastCompletedOffset();
    if (_committedTo != lastCompletedOffset) {
        LOG.debug("Writing last completed offset (" + lastCompletedOffset + ") to ZK for " + _partition + " for topology: " + _topologyInstanceId);
        Map<Object, Object> data = (Map<Object, Object>) ImmutableMap.builder()
                .put("topology", ImmutableMap.of("id", _topologyInstanceId,
                        "name", _stormConf.get(Config.TOPOLOGY_NAME)))
                .put("offset", lastCompletedOffset)
                .put("partition", _partition.partition)
                .put("broker", ImmutableMap.of("host", _partition.host.host,
                        "port", _partition.host.port))
                .put("topic", _spoutConfig.topic).build();
        _state.writeJSON(committedPath(), data);

        _committedTo = lastCompletedOffset;
        LOG.debug("Wrote last completed offset (" + lastCompletedOffset + ") to ZK for " + _partition + " for topology: " + _topologyInstanceId);
    } else {
        LOG.debug("No new offset for " + _partition + " for topology: " + _topologyInstanceId);
    }
}
```

ZkState

```
public void writeBytes(String path, byte[] bytes) {
    try {
        if (_curator.checkExists().forPath(path) == null) {
            _curator.create()
                    .creatingParentsIfNeeded()
                    .withMode(CreateMode.PERSISTENT)
                    .forPath(path, bytes);
        } else {
            _curator.setData().forPath(path, bytes);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

I could see that for the first message, the `writeBytes` method gets into the `if` block and tries to create a path, then for the second message it goes into the `else` block, which seems to be ok. But when I start the project again, the same message as mentioned above shows up. No `partition information` can be found.

Comment: hello Juto, I met the problems... have you fixed this problem? thank you, i am waiting for you now

Comment: Hi @kaitian, I left the company which I did this project for, therefore I don't have access to the code anymore, I never had a solution for this problem. :(

Comment: Anthony's answer works and the reason is quite obvious as in Local Mode, the zookeeper is different from the one which is used by kafka !

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem.  Turned out I was running in local mode which uses an in memory zookeeper and not the zookeeper that Kafka is using.

To make sure that KafkaSpout doesn't use Storm's ZooKeeper for the `ZkState` that stores the offset, you need to set the `SpoutConfig.zkServers`, `SpoutConfig.zkPort`, and `SpoutConfig.zkRoot` in addition to the `ZkHosts`.  For example

```java
import org.apache.zookeeper.client.ConnectStringParser;
import storm.kafka.SpoutConfig;
import storm.kafka.ZkHosts;
import storm.kafka.KeyValueSchemeAsMultiScheme;

...

    final ConnectStringParser connectStringParser = new ConnectStringParser(zkConnectStr);
    final List<InetSocketAddress> serverInetAddresses = connectStringParser.getServerAddresses();
    final List<String> serverAddresses = new ArrayList<>(serverInetAddresses.size());
    final Integer zkPort = serverInetAddresses.get(0).getPort();
    for (InetSocketAddress serverInetAddress : serverInetAddresses) {
        serverAddresses.add(serverInetAddress.getHostName());
    }

    final ZkHosts zkHosts = new ZkHosts(zkConnectStr);
    zkHosts.brokerZkPath = kafkaZnode + zkHosts.brokerZkPath;

    final SpoutConfig spoutConfig = new SpoutConfig(zkHosts, inputTopic, kafkaZnode, kafkaConsumerGroup);
    spoutConfig.scheme = new KeyValueSchemeAsMultiScheme(inputKafkaKeyValueScheme);

    spoutConfig.zkServers = serverAddresses;
    spoutConfig.zkPort = zkPort;
    spoutConfig.zkRoot = kafkaZnode;
```

Comment: just to make the answer easier to grasp: when you have a working topology ready to deploy on remote server, add 3 last lines to make it connect to remote zookeeper when used in local mode

Answer (score 0):

I think you are hitting this bug:

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/66524/closedchannelexception-kafka-spout-cannot-read-kaf.html

And the comment from the colleague above fixed my issue. I added some newer libraries to.