# Storm KafkaSpout can't read offset when topic partition more than 1

Tags: offset, apache-kafka, apache-storm

My KafkaSpout set is

```
    SpoutConfig spoutConf = new SpoutConfig(brokerHosts, topic, zkRoot,clientId);
    spoutConf.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
    spoutConf.forceFromStart = false;
    spoutConf.zkServers=...
    spoutConf.zkPort = 2181;
    spoutConf.zkHost = ...
    spoutConf.zkRoot = zkRoot;
```

just like the [Failing to write offset data to zookeeper in kafka-storm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24408063/failing-to-write-offset-data-to-zookeeper-in-kafka-storm),
but I found,when my topic partition is bigger than 1, my KafkaSpout can't read offset from zookeeper and there are no settings in zookeeper.